# Why does the query take a long time in mysql even with a LIMIT clause?

Tags: mysql

Say I have an Order table that has 100+ columns and 1 million rows. It has a PK on OrderID and FK constraint StoreID --> Store.StoreID.

1) `select * from 'Order' order by OrderID desc limit 10;`

the above takes a few milliseconds.

2) `select * from 'Order' o join 'Store' s on s.StoreID = o.StoreID order by OrderID desc limit 10;`

this somehow can take up to many seconds. The more inner joins I add, slows it down further more.

3) `select OrderID, column1 from 'Order' o join 'Store' s on s.StoreID = o.StoreID order by OrderID desc limit 10;`

this seems to speed the execution up, by limiting the columns we select.

There are a few points that I dont understand here and would really appreciate it if anyone more knowledgeable with mysql (or rmdb query execution in general) can enlighten me.

Query 1 is fast since it's just a reverse lookup by PK and DB only needs to return the first 10 rows it encountered.

I don't see why Query 2 should take for ever. Shouldn't the operation be the same? i.e. get the first 10 rows by PK and *then* join with other tables. Since there's a FK constraint, it is guaranteed that the relationship will be satisfied. So DB doesn't need to join more rows than necessary and then trim the result, right? Unless, FK constraint allows null FK? In which case I guess a left join would make this much faster than an inner join?

Lastly, I'm guess query 3 is simply faster because less columns are used in those unnecessary joins?  But why would the query execution need the other columns while joining? Shouldn't it just join using PKs first, and then get the columns for just the 10 rows?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a table with 100 columns in it, then something is very wrong with the design of the table.  As a rule of thumb, RDBMS's are good at long thin tables, so long as you can apply sensible btree indexes.

Comment: While it's easy to point out bad designs, one does not simply write everything from scratch or re-design/re-write at the first chance one gets. =)

Comment: Xerion: Actually it's not easy to point out a bad design -- if it were there would be less bad design.  It actually requires an understanding of the fundamental concepts behind relational databases, and some experience with effective design patterns.  I don't however need any of those to say, that when you stipulate that you have a table with 100+ columns, that design is completely wrongheaded.  I understand that it *might* not be your design and that you might not be able to change it, but you're also painted into a corner where things that should be easy AND performant are neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the mysql engine applies `limit` after any `join`'s happen.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, `The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)`

EDIT: You could try using this query to take advantage of the PK speed.

`select * from (select * from 'Order' order by OrderID desc limit 10) o
join 'Store' s on s.StoreID = o.StoreID;`

Comment: aside from readability / formatting in the answer, your final query is exactly what I would have proposed...

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples are asking for tablescans of the existing tables, so none of them will be more or less performant than the degree to which mysql can cache the data or results.  Some of your queries have order by or join criteria, which can take advantage of indexes purely to make the joining process more efficient, however, that still is not the same as having a set of criteria that will trigger the use of indexes.

Limit is not a criteria -- it can be thought of as filtration once a result set is determined.  You save time on the client, once the result set is prepared, but not on the server.

Really, the only way to get the answers you are seeking is to become familiar with:
    EXPLAIN EXTENDED your_sql_statement

The output of EXPLAIN will show you how many rows are being looked at by mysql, as well as whether or not any indexes are being used.